# How to compile project in Visual Studio without running after build?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, build, project, execution

How to compile project in Visual Studio without running after build? I'm compiling a dll extension, but Visual Studio is trying to run it (inconvenient), then an error occurs. Can I avoid this running?

Comment: Just build it by ctrl+shift+b

Comment: Is there an alternative option for project settings?

Comment: not such setting available.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the shortcut "CTRL+SHIFT+B" and it will just build without running.

Comment: After hitting enter :)